# Can't access another http resource from ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

I am working on Ionic framework , i am trying to access an Restful API using $http service in my Ionic framework i ma getting the following error in console.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://apiexample.com/token/ Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

Anyone know how to access that Rest full API from my Angular Js using `$http` service ?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a setting that you need to enable on the server side.  Ensure you have the right CORS settings on the server side.